# Maven compile kotlin and java with generated sources

Tags: java, maven, kotlin, code-generation, annotation-processing

I have a kotlin project in which some code is generated using Annotation Processing (AbstractProcessor). The generated code is in java and is generated into

> ./target/generated-sources/annotations

the generated code accesses some kotlin classes and with the following build configuration in java, everything compiles just fine

```
<build>
    <finalName>xxx</finalName>
    <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/kotlin</testSourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <args>
                    <arg>-Xjsr305=strict</arg>
                </args>
                <compilerPlugins>
                    <plugin>spring</plugin>
                </compilerPlugins>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
                    <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>

            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>compile</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceDirs>
                            <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDir>
                            <sourceDir>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/annotations</sourceDir>
                        </sourceDirs>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>test-compile</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test-compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceDirs>
                            <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/test/kotlin</sourceDir>
                            <sourceDir>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/annotations</sourceDir>
                        </sourceDirs>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <executions>
                <!-- Replacing default-compile as it is treated specially by maven -->
                <execution>
                    <id>default-compile</id>
                    <phase>none</phase>
                </execution>
                <!-- Replacing default-testCompile as it is treated specially by maven -->
                <execution>
                    <id>default-testCompile</id>
                    <phase>none</phase>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>java-compile</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals> <goal>compile</goal> </goals>
                    
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>

        <!--
            Take care of synchronizing java dependencies and imports in
            package.json and main.js files.
            It also creates webpack.config.js if not exists yet.
        -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-frontend</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

However, when I want to use the generated classes within my Kotlin project, maven doesn't compile anymore with the following error:

> mvn clean package spring-boot:repackage -Pproduction -DskipTests=true

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-maven-plugin:1.7.22:compile (compile) on project xxx: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /path/to/project/src/main/kotlin/com/x/y/z/View.kt:[12,44] Unresolved reference: CRUD
[ERROR] /path/to/project/src/main/kotlin/com/x/y/z/View.kt:[35,38] Unresolved reference: XxxCRUDController
```

any ideas how I can use my generated Java classes within my Kotlin project?

Comment: Are these 2 distinct Maven projects? I'm trying to understand what you mean by 'within my Kotlin project'

Comment: @D-Dᴙum no, it is only one (kotlin) project. it has some libraries as dependency and using one of them I generate some (java) code as described above.

Comment: I don't have experience with Kotlin, is it really necessary that you configure the sourceDirs in the plugin? I would try to remove that part, but if you have to specify it, you also have to add the generated sources somehow, otherwise the Kotlin plugin doesn't know about them. See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/maven.html#compile-kotlin-and-java-sources

Comment: @cyberbrain thanks for your input. I kinda used that link you shared as a basis for my configuration. I think the generated source dir in the maven plugin isn't necessary as sit seems to be the default value. I added the generated dir in the kotlin maven plugin and it didn't make a difference. I guess you might be right that it should be in there, therefore I'll leave it in. but unfortunately it won't still compile

Comment: (I answered already, but:) could you point out the exact difference between "working" and "not working" (.i.e. for "non working", you did `mvn clean package spring-boot:repackage...`, how can you produce the "working" one?)

Comment: when "working"/"everything compiles just fine" means "in IDE", then only due to just-in-time compilation of the IDE, and my answer could hold ;)

Comment: @xerx593 ah I just commented in your answer ;) working means also build in maven. I have my kotlin code, which doesn't reference any of the generated sources (the in the error messages mentioned View.kt is not present). I also have generated code which references kotlin code. compiling in maven with my config (see my post) ends successfully, source code is generated, all classes are compiled and present in my target directory.

Comment: when I add the View.kt, which references the generated java code, I cannot build anymore in maven